# Extract elements using cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to write nodejs code, that take an argument from user as a singer name, then go to the specified singer page in  `https://www.billboard.com/charts/rap-song`, and print all of their songs' name

For example if I run: `Node Singer.js Drake`, it will go to drake page, and print all his songs,

I don't know how to do that, can someone help me please.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const args = process.argv;  

request('https://www.billboard.com/charts/rap-song', function(error,response,html){
if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){

     var $ = cheerio.load(html);
   $('a.chart-row__artist').each(function(i, element) {
            if(i%2==1 && i<20){
                console.log($(this).text());
                  }
        });
}
});
```

Comment: Where `it will go to drake page` satisfied?

Comment: https://www.billboard.com/music/drake

Comment: like this  " https://www.billboard.com/music/drake  "

Comment: or any other singer "https://www.billboard.com/music/SingerName"

Comment: And where you use the name in your code?? You must use it in your url, right?

Comment: yes, like if the user type drake, it goes to drake page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var url = "https://www.billboard.com/music/" + singerName;

request({
  uri: url,
  timeout: 120000
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (typeof body === 'undefined') {
      console.log("error");
  } else {

     var $ = cheerio.load(html);
     $('a.chart-row__artist').each(function(i, element) {
        if(i%2==1 && i<20){
            console.log(element);
        }
     });

  }
});
```

Use correct Url for requesting and then, with `Cheerio` select right elements you want. I do not check the site.

Comment: I checked, and used the right elements, it still not printing anything..

Comment: What,s the problem? did you console the body?? it that true?

Comment: when i try to print just the URL, it shows me this,

Comment: https://www.billboard.com/music/C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe,C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test1.js,drake

Comment: Use static name `draco` in your URL

Comment: i did console, but nothing showing up,  and when I print URL, it shows me like 
billboard.com/music/C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node.exe,C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test1.js,drake

Comment: Use `process.argv[2]` for singerName

Comment: I VERY APPRECIATE it.